# How to merge some data in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge some data in dataframe because I will code [sequential association rule] in python.

How can I merge the data and what algorithm I should use in python?
Apriori? FP growth?
I can't find [sequential association rule] using apriori in python.
They use R

visit places are 250. unique id numbers are 116807 and total row is 1.7millions. and, each id has country_code(111 countries but I will classify them to 10 countries).. so I will merge them one more.

Previous Data

```
index     date_ymd      id     visit_nm   country
1         20170801    123123    seoul      460
2         20170801    123123    tokyo      460
3         20170801    124567    seoul      440
4         20170802    123123    osaka      460
5         20170802    123123    seoul      460
...         ...         ...      ...
```

What I need

```
index    Transaction           visit_nm      country
1        20170801123123      {seoul,tokyo}     460
2        20170802123123      {osaka,seoul}     460
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understood seeing the data, Use groupby agg:

```
s=pd.Series(df.date_ymd.astype(str)+df.id.astype(str),name='Transaction')
(df.groupby(s)
 .agg({'visit_nm':lambda x: set(x),'country':'first'}).reset_index())
```

---

```
      Transaction        visit_nm  country
0  20170801123123  {seoul, tokyo}      460
1  20170801124567         {seoul}      440
2  20170802123123  {osaka, seoul}      460
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use:

```
df['Transaction'] = df['date_ymd'].map(str)+df['id'].map(str)
df.groupby('Transaction').agg({'visit_nm': lambda x: set(x), 'country': 'first'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: yes! It also worked and it is still in dataframe not in series.! thx!! :)

Comment: @nazonobunkeisei kindly upvote if you find the answer useful :)